# Google+ Signin callback function not found if inside a module

Tags: google-plus

I'm having some strange issue when I place the callback function inside a module, the library cannot seem to find the function, so if I use:

```
var Auth = (function () {
    var gPlusSignCallback = function () {
      console.log("Google plus signin call back done!");
  };

  return {
      gPlusSignCallback: gPlusSignCallback
  };
}());
```

And in the html snipped of the Google+ Signing button I use:

```
data-callback="Auth.gPlusSignCallback"
```

I get the following error:

> Callback function named "Auth.gPlusSignCallback" not found

If I put the gPlusSignCallback outside the module everything works well. I checked the documentation and it says that the value must be a function in the global namespace. So is it not working by design? I need to make global variable that makes reference to the function in the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signin callback must be a global function for the widget to find it. Wrap your callback as such:

```
function onSigninCallback(e){
    Auth.gPlusSignCallback(e);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Was curious, is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: The reason is that the sign-in button is using a string to specify the function. As such, there is no clean (e.g. not use eval) way to get the non-global / private closure function reference via string.

As Silvano mentions, you can directly render using JavaScript as opposed to markup if you don't want to have the global callback.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use the [Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#javascript_api) to render the button. If you do that, you can pass a reference to a function as callback.
[This is](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-photohunt-server-java/blob/master/war/js/controllers.js#L234) an example from PhotoHunt, the End-to-end Google+ Platform sample application.